# Old numbers can't change in numpy.convolve and Python

Tags: python, numpy, fixed

I am working with numpy.convolve. To be honest I am not sure if I am using the correct module for the project I am working.

I want numpy convolve (or if there is any other module I can implement) not to change previous numbers. I don't want the old numbers changed I want them to be fixed. So when I get new data the only number that should be affect is the new one, not the rest.

Here is an example to clarify:

```
import numpy 

N = 3
numbers = [11,-5,54,-100,1]
numbers_mean  = numpy.convolve(numbers, numpy.ones((N,))/N)[(N-1):]
print numbers_mean
```

Output:

```
[ 20.         -17.         -15.         -33.           0.33333333]
```

But when I change the last number to 100 instead of 1 the result changes all 3 numbers.

```
N = 3
numbers = [11,-5,54,-100,100]
numbers_mean  = numpy.convolve(numbers, numpy.ones((N,))/N)[(N-1):]
print numbers_mean
```

Output:

```
[ 20.         -17.          18.           0.          33.33333333]
```

**JUST THE OUTPUTS:**

```
[ 20.         -17.         -15.         -33.           0.33333333]
[ 20.         -17.          18.           0.          33.33333333]
```

**THIS IS WHAT I WANT TO SEE:**

```
[ 20.         -17.         -15.         -33.           33.33333333<- this number only should change not the rest]
```

So as you can see when the number goes from 1 to 100 it changed the -33. to 0. This is not what I want I want all of those numbers to be fixed and none changing the only number that should be able to change is the newest number. in this case 33.333333 from 0.3333

Is there any module or way I can implement this in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to compute 3-neighborhood  means. So you have a `mask=[1./3,1./3,1./3]` which size is `N`.

See what happen on a simpler example , `numbers = [0,1,2,3,4]` , which size is `M>=N` :

```
In [1]: numpy.convolve(numbers,mask)
Out[1]: 
array([ 0.        ,  0.33333333,  1.        ,  2.        ,  3.        ,
        2.33333333,  1.33333333])
```

This is an  array  with `N+M-1` elements . There are only `M-2(N-1)` valid means, [1,2,3] here, and `N-1` overlapping means at the beginning and at the END : You must discard them too.

For your case :

```
N = 3
a1 = [11,-5,54,-100,1]
a2 = [11,-5,54,-100,100]

mask=numpy.ones(N)/N
m1= numpy.convolve(a1, mask)[(N-1):-(N-1)]
m2= numpy.convolve(a2, mask)[(N-1):-(N-1)]
print (m1,m2)

# [ 20. -17. -15.] [ 20. -17.  18.]
```

Only the last term is affected.

### Edit

To avoid the `N-1` last terms, an other approach is to use [`scipy.signal.lfilter`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.0/reference/generated/scipy.signal.lfilter.html),  which implement differences equations :

Here, `mean(n) - mean(n-1) =  data(n)/N  -data(n-N)/N` .

```
from scipy.signal import lfilter
N=3
a=np.array([1,-1])
b=np.concatenate(([1],np.zeros(N-1),[-1]))/N
x=np.arange(5)
means=lfilter(b,a,x)
# array([0.,0.3333,1.,2.,3.])
```

Comment: What would be the calculation on the 4th number? I can not have the data lagging. it needs to be leading. So all numbers need to have a calculation for example if I have 5 numbers I want to find the average [2+3+4+1+8]/5 = 3.6 . Next I get new data Now I have total of 6 numbers  [2+3+4+1+8+4] and I want to divide it by 5 again(ALWAYS lets say) now I take  [3+4+1+8+4]/5 = 4 . Again I get new data, now I have total of 7 numbers [2+3+4+1+8+4+9] and I divide by 5 so [4+1+8+4+9]/5 = 5.2. this is what I want convolve to do. is it possible???

Comment: I proposed an other approach, but I am not sure that I understand your  goal. all these method need to recompute all the means  on each new data.

Comment: thank you for clarifying the convole for me. furthermore, I will try this formula tmwr on my full data. the only thing is zeros should be np.zeros and arrange should be np.arange I think. :) thank you again

Answer (score 0):

i'm not a numpy expert, so i will propose you a Python solution for that:

```
In [342]: fixed = np.convolve([11,-5,54,-100,1], np.ones((N,))/N)[(N-1):-1]

In [343]: fixed
Out[343]: array([ 20., -17., -15., -33.])

In [344]: np.append(fixed, np.convolve([11,-5,54,-100,100], np.ones((N,))/N)[-1])
Out[344]: array([ 20.        , -17.        , -15.        , -33.        ,  33.33333333])
```

Comment: This sort of works the only problem is, it only changes the last number. I need it to do it every 3 numbers. so the whole data reflects the real stochastic. Any advice?